# Метатег <meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height">. Как на телефонах при появлении клавиатуры запретить менять высоту?

Tags: html, css

Я хочу написать сайт, в котором скроллить можно только внутри моего блока, а не внутри body. Я использую метатег

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0" />`.

При появлении клавиатуры высота сайта меняется. Как это отменить? Пусть скроллится body, но высота не уменьшается.